# jquery autocomplete results to appear over other input elements

Tags: jquery, css, autocomplete

Using jquery autocomplete on an input box. This is working 100% but think the styling needs some work.

Currently the jquery suggestions are being displayed behind the text of other input elements. If I click on a jquery option that is below my select box, the select box is triggered rather than the autocomplete option being selected.

how can I configure the jquery autocomplete to be on top? is this a js issue or a css issue?

I have tried to disable the other input element, named period with the below code but it doesn't work:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(function(){
        $("#customer").autocomplete({
          minlength: 5,
          source: "get_customers",
           open: function(event, ui) { // disable other inputs
        $("input#period").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    },
      close: function(event, ui) { // re-enable other inputs
        $("input#period").removeAttr("disabled");
    },
          messages: {
          noResults: '',
          results: function() {}
      }


        });
      });
</script>
```

Any advice would be appreciated either on getting the jquery list 'ontop' or the disabling other forms working.

Comment: can i see the live link it might b z-index issue ... use z-index in your css

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try

```
.ui-autocomplete{
   z-index:50;       //Where 50 is just an arbitrary number superior to your form's z-indexes
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I can't see your html markup so can't provide an example but you need to use the [z-index](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_z-index.asp) css property to resolve this.

You need to use it on the container that contains all the suggestions. You might even need to set it on some background elements but that's unlikely if you haven't used it already.

I generally set mine to 999 like so:

```
z-index: 999;
```

just to make sure it stays on top.

Answer (score 2):

use z-index property

```
    .ui-autocomplete
{
       z-index:50;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> Use appendTo:YourContainerDiv

```
$("#TextBox").autocomplete({
                appendTo: '.ContainerDiv',
                source: function (request, response) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '@Url.Action("Action","Controller")',
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: { Prefix: request.term },
                        success: function (data) {
                            response($.map(data, function (item) {
                                return { label: item.Name, value: item.Name };
                            }));

                        }
                    })
                }

            });
```